# c# htmlDecode entities number greater than 127

Tags: c#

Hello, I would like to decode html entities but I have an issues when the entities numbers is greater than 127.

I am using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`

Example :

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "`&deg;&bull;&raquo;ZE&#1071;O&laquo;&bull;&deg;&acute;";
        Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

> Output : `°»ZE?O«°´ and not : `°•»ZEЯO«•°´

The problems is that entities is not decoded correctly.

```
&#1071;
```

I would like to know how can I decode it, I did a lot of search and I was not able to find a solution...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with WebUtility.HtmlDecode - if you step through you'll see the representation is fine in Visual Studio. The problem is that the Console can't, by default, display Unicode.